# In a forex statement summary, what does "posted at statement period of time" mean?

Tags: fx, cfd, rollover

My question probably is the result of my lack of knowledge of the English language. I am located in Germany and have an account with FXCM, a company that enables private people to participate at forex / CFD markets (currencies, indices, commodities). They provide a yearly state summary that I use as a basis for my tax declaration.

With the summary statement for 2022, I have a problem that I haven't encountered in the years before:

In the **summary of closed trades,** there is a line that is titled "Total". This line designates the rollover fees to be 14,82 EUR. In the **same summary of closed trades,** there is also a line titled "Posted at statement period of time". This line designates the rollover fees to be 75,50 EUR.

Could somebody please explain what "posted" in this conjunction means and why the rollover fees differ? I'd like to stress again that **both lines are in the same table** of closed trades.

Comment: posted (English) = gebucht (German), in English you could also say "booked"

Comment: OK, thanks a lot, and +1. However, what does that actually mean? One line says that the "Total:" rollover fees are 14,82 EUR, and the next line says that the "Posted at statement period of time:" rollover fees are 75,50 EUR. What exactly do those two number relate to? Why are there two numbers for the rollover fees at all?

Comment: It is not obvious, In my experience these types of problems are solved either by contacting the brokerage firm, or by talking to other customers of the same firm. FXCM is a small frm but they must have a customer service dept.

Comment: OK, thanks again, and +1. I'll do that. The reason I was asking here is that I had to finish my private tax declaration for 2022 until 2023-12-31 and that I had noticed the problem too late to ask FXCM. They have a holiday season, too, and don't work on Saturdays or Sundays :-)